# Add custom seasonality in fbprophet

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have a dataset with monthly frequency(one record per month). It has two seasonalities in it:

1. 12(monthly)
2. 96(8 years)

How do I add these in my fbprophet model using add_seasonality?

I tried:

```
m = Prophet(seasonality_mode='additive', 
            yearly_seasonality=True, 
            weekly_seasonality=False, 
            daily_seasonality=False).add_seasonality(name='8_years', period=96, fourier_order = 20)
```

Is this the correct method?

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything in the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#specifying-custom-seasonalities).

> The inputs to this function are a name, the period of the seasonality in days, and the Fourier order for the seasonality.

Your script should be

```
m = Prophet(seasonality_mode='additive', 
        yearly_seasonality=True, 
        weekly_seasonality=False, 
        daily_seasonality=False).add_seasonality(name='8_years', period=8*365, fourier_order = 20)
```